# Mongodb sort by version x.y.z

Tags: mongodb, sorting

Our application is based on MongoDB. We store the "names", "versions" and various attributes of IT assets in MongoDB. We have a new search requirement in which we need to retrieve the latest version of assets based on keywords. The catch here is that my versions numbers are of the format 
x.y.z (i.e. major.minor.maintenance)

Basically, I should have the result set sorted first by major version (desc), then minor version (desc) and then maintenance version (desc). 
e.g. For the version numbers given below: 
1.0.10 
1.1.0 
11.0.0 
2.0.1 
The sorted version should be: 
1.0.10 
1.2.10 
2.0.1 
11.0.0 
Is it possible for me to sort this correctly at Mongo layer itself? Unfortunately the version number is just stored as a single string value, and not a structured object in the x.y.z format.

Thanks in advance! 
Zeba

Comment: You could perform a one-time task and break this version string to individual components, so that it's more queryable.

Comment: I did consider doing that, but trying to avoid that for now, since there are various dependencies to it for my application..

Comment: To avoid breaking your dependencies, create another version field, deriving from the one you already have, and use it for sorting.

Comment: Normally yould have 4 fields: `version`, `major`, `minor`, `patch`

Comment: @Rafa Not sure I get you. My search requirement is new, but my collections/documents are the existing ones in db. Is it possible for me to derive a virtual field without modifying an existing one??

Comment: @Sammaye Hmm I agree that looks like how it should be done .. Unfortunately there is existing/historical data which doesn't strictly conform to the x.y.z scheme and I'm not in a position to fix those right now

Comment: If versions are not standardised how to do you expect to sort them standardised, i.e. how can you sort general versioning correctly compared to semantic versioning

Comment: @user Yes, I'm suggesting you create a little redundancy to make you life in coding a bit easier. Write a data migration script to create a second field, derived from the one you have, so that you can easily sort. In the application, write code to keep the derived field up-to-date. Both should be trivial tasks.

Answer (score 5):

You need to store a second representation of the field, mongo can't sort on semantic versions. I chose to pad each component to 4 characters.

```
var document = {
  version: "1.2.3",
  padded_version: "0001.0002.0003",
}
```

Then you can sort on lexicographic string index.

```
db.ensureIndex({ padded_version: -1 })
```

You can also bit-shift each component:

```
var document = {
  version: "1.2.3",
  integer_version: 1 << 16 + 2 << 8 + 3,
}
```

It limits you to 256 new versions however with potential overflow issues, etc. I would stick with zero-padded string version.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not the one of the most recent questions, but I have a different solution.

Option with one projection (slower):

```
{$project: {
  version: {
    major: { $arrayElemAt: [{ $map: { input: { $split: ["$metadata.appVersion", "."] }, as: "vn", in: { $toInt: "$$vn" } } }, 0] },
    minor: { $arrayElemAt: [{ $map: { input: { $split: ["$metadata.appVersion", "."] }, as: "vn", in: { $toInt: "$$vn" } } }, 1] },
    patch: { $arrayElemAt: [{ $map: { input: { $split: ["$metadata.appVersion", "."] }, as: "vn", in: { $toInt: "$$vn" } } }, 2] }
  }
}
```

Option with two projections (aggregate needed):

```
{
  $project: {
    versionAsArray: { 
      $map: { 
        input: { 
          $split: ["$metadata.appVersion", "."] 
        }, 
        as: "vn", 
        in: { $toInt: "$$vn" } 
      } 
    }
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    version: {
      version: {
        major: { $arrayElemAt: ["$versionAsArray", 0] },
        minor: { $arrayElemAt: ["$versionAsArray", 1] },
        patch: { $arrayElemAt: ["$versionAsArray", 2] },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and on the end you can use normal `$sort: { version: 1 }`

Answer (score 1):

Just iterating on what @kpostekk suggested. The only difference is using dot notation to access major, minor and patch versions during the `$sort` (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#query-for-an-element-by-the-array-index-position). I think it's a bit cleaner but am not sure about the performance difference between that and using `$arrayElemAt`.

```js
const cursor = mongoDB.collection().aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id:           0,
      semVer:        1,
      semVerAsArray: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $split: ['$semVer', '.'],
          },
          as:    'versionStringAsDigit',
          in:    { $toInt: '$$versionStringAsDigit' }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      'semVerAsArray.0': -1,
      'semVerAsArray.1': -1,
      'semVerAsArray.2': -1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      semVerAsArray: 0
    }
  }
])

const latestVersion = await cursor.next()
```

Given documents in the collection:

```js
[
  { semVer: '1.0.9' },
  { semVer: '1.0.12' },
]
```

The above would output `{ semVer: '1.0.12' }`. While the lexicographic `$sort` would return `{ serVer: '1.0.9' }`